# Getting following error after the command sudo apt-get update on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, sudo, ubuntu-16.04

I have no knowledge on Linux commands but I couldn't resist asking why such errors are showing after the command `sudo apt-get update`:

> W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
>
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>
> W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
>
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>
> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 799A5FD5D1C5997F
>
> W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
>
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>
> E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I would like to know what's exactly going on with the following errors. An explanation would be very helpful for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is belongs to another Stack Exchange Forum

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error during install node js in debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251703/error-during-install-node-js-in-debian)

Answer (score 31):

I solved this error following theses steps:

Open the Software Updates application;
 - In "Other Software" tab unmark all options;
 - In Ubuntu Software tab, "Download from:" choose "Main server" option.

Click in "Close" button and wait a minute until ubuntu reload apt-get.

Done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked but is it going to affect any future updates? And what happened to the error? Are they still there but not showing because I have checked so many thing out? @Willian

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone getting an error like this, this means some apt repository is not active. So simply disable that.

Firstly, go to your Discover or software update application then select setting. Then disable that option for which you are getting that error. Wait for a minute. Done!

Comment: I'm working on a WSL and I only have a prompt, how can I do those things using commandline commands?

Answer (score 0):

The following commands will resolve the issue,

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list"

wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O Release.key

sudo apt-key add - < Release.key

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. I would not run any such stuff on my system - why should I add a random URL from opensuse.org to my Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ubuntu 20.04. please try followings.

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ubuntu:/debbuild/Ubuntu_20.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list"

wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Ubuntu:/debbuild/Ubuntu_20.04/Release.key -O Release.key

sudo apt-key add - < Release.key

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the @Codemaker answer? He post it first.

Comment: The only difference is the Ubuntu version.